# How to make a new Icon in css?

Tags: css, sass

I'm not sure whether the title is correct But I have a custom png file that I want to apply as an icon in an existing application. Because this is an existing application, I can't make too many changes in order to keep the consistency. The only thing that I have to do is by using icon tag.

```
<i class="icon name" />
```

I've tried to create a new class and set the background image.

```
.new-icon {
  background-image: url("./img/icon.png")
}
```

After that I applied that class in an icon tag like

```
<i class="new-icon" />
```

But the image didn't show at all. What I should do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<img>` tag for png files but if you want to create something that you use in `<i>` you should create your icons as a font file, I suggest you to use `<img>` tag.

Comment: You're welcome, making an icon is not as easy as you think. I suggest you use SVG

Comment: I am not a designer so I can't feel that difficulties. the file is from the design team so I will follow it up to them. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You can design your SVG from here https://editor.method.ac/. If it helped. Please vote down or up.

Comment: sure. this is so helpful

Answer (score 1):

You should design your icon as SVG, then you can make it web fonts from here: https://fontello.com/

You can not use png as an icon.